# Efficiency of multiple threads reading the same file

Tags: multithreading, performance, file

Will reading from the same file make threads run slower? If so, how does YouTube or Netflix servers handle so many people watching the same movie and everyone is at different place in the movie?

Or if reading from the same file make threads slow, then if space is not a concern, is it better to have multiple copies of the file, or split the file into parts?

Answer (score 0):

> Will reading from the same file make threads run slower?

No. Modern operating systems handle this situation extremely efficiently.